# Unknown: KeyError: 'pyfunc_0'

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensor

I am exporting a savedModel which takes a string placeholder as the input tensor. I injected a graph to preprocess this string tensor so that it can be passed into the model. However, I am using `py_func` to perform my python string operations on the tensor.

Here `input_text` is the input tensor in the savedModel signature. I created another placeholder with default `input_ints`  which is initialized with result of performing `py_func` on `input_text`. I initially had input_text as an operation (`input_ints =tf.py_func(preprocess, [input_text], tf.int64)`) but then `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` was not accepting a tensor with unspecified shape.

```
    # Create the graph object
with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
    input_text = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name="input_text")
    input_ints = tf.placeholder_with_default(
        tf.py_func(preprocess, [input_text], tf.int64), shape=[None, None])

def lstm_cell():
    # Your basic LSTM cell
    lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size, reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)
    # Add dropout to the cell
    return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)


# def create_rnn():
with tf.name_scope("Embeddings"):
    embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((vocab_size, embed_size), -1, 1))
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, input_ints)
with tf.name_scope("RNN_layers"):
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for _ in range(lstm_layers)])
initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
with tf.name_scope("RNN_forward"):
    outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, embed, initial_state=initial_state)
with tf.name_scope('predictions'):
    predictions = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs[:, -1], 1, activation_fn=tf.sigmoid)
```

Now using the above implementation, I can export the model properly but when restoring the model, I get the following error:

```
2017-11-23 17:29:14.600184: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Unknown: KeyError: 'pyfunc_0'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sakibarrahman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1327, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Users/sakibarrahman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1306, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/sakibarrahman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 89, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/sakibarrahman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: KeyError: 'pyfunc_0'
     [[Node: inputs/PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_INT64], token="pyfunc_0", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_inputs/input_text_0_0)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neural_load_model.py", line 85, in <module>
    result = sess.run(output_tensor, {input_tensor: "Charter Communications, Inc. (CHTR) Stock Rating Reaffirmed by Goldman Sachs Group, Inc. (The)"})
  File "/Users/sakibarrahman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/sakibarrahman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/sakibarrahman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/sakibarrahman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: KeyError: 'pyfunc_0'
     [[Node: inputs/PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_INT64], token="pyfunc_0", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_inputs/input_text_0_0)]]

Caused by op 'inputs/PyFunc', defined at:
  File "neural_load_model.py", line 74, in <module>
    model = tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], import_path)
  File "/Users/sakibarrahman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 216, in load
    saver = tf_saver.import_meta_graph(meta_graph_def_to_load, **saver_kwargs)
  File "/Users/sakibarrahman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1698, in import_meta_graph
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sakibarrahman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 656, in import_scoped_meta_graph
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
  File "/Users/sakibarrahman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 313, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/sakibarrahman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/sakibarrahman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

UnknownError (see above for traceback): KeyError: 'pyfunc_0'
     [[Node: inputs/PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_INT64], token="pyfunc_0", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_inputs/input_text_0_0)]]
```

I have looked at this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12073) posted on Github but I am not sure as to how to implement this. Also, I am just loading the model and passing in a string for input and not using 'freeze_graph'.

My code for saving the model:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()

#Define new functions
def preprocess(text):
.
.
.
tf.reset_default_graph()
.
.
.
#Define new placeholder that was not in the original model graph
#Define new placeholder with default value initialized with py_func that was not in the original model graph
with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
    input_text = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name="input_text")
    input_ints = tf.placeholder_with_default(
        tf.py_func(preprocess, [input_text], tf.int64), shape=[None, None])
.
.
.
#Define placeholders and ops that I need and were in the original graph



saver = tf.train.Saver()
#Serving the model
with tf.Session() as sess:


#Restore from old checkpoint
saver.restore(sess, import_path)

print ('Exporting trained model to %s'%(export_path))

builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

original_assets_directory = export_path + '/assets'
original_assets_filename = "vocabulary.pickle"
original_assets_filepath = write_vocab(original_assets_directory,
                                         original_assets_filename)

# Set up the assets collection.
assets_filepath = tf.constant(original_assets_filepath)
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.ASSET_FILEPATHS, assets_filepath)
filename_tensor = tf.Variable(
    original_assets_filename,
    name="vocab_tensor",
    trainable=False,
    collections=[])
assign_filename_op = filename_tensor.assign(original_assets_filename)


# Build the signature_def_map.
classification_inputs = utils.build_tensor_info(input_text)
classification_outputs_classes = utils.build_tensor_info(predictions)
classification_signature = signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs={signature_constants.CLASSIFY_INPUTS: classification_inputs},
    outputs={
      signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_CLASSES:
          classification_outputs_classes,
    },
  method_name=signature_constants.CLASSIFY_METHOD_NAME)

legacy_init_op = tf.group(
    tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')
#add the sigs to the servable
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
    sess, [tag_constants.SERVING],
    signature_def_map={
        signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
            classification_signature
    },
    assets_collection=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.ASSET_FILEPATHS),
    legacy_init_op=tf.group(assign_filename_op))
print ("added meta graph and variables")

builder.save()
print("model saved")
```

My code for loading the model. Not defining the function or the placeholders leads to the 'pyfunc_0' error:

```
#Define preprocess function
def preprocess(text_bin):

#Define new placeholders
with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
    input_text = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name="input_text")
    input_ints = tf.placeholder_with_default(
        tf.py_func(preprocess, [input_text], tf.int64), shape=[None, None])

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    # restore save model
    model = tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], import_path)
    print("model restored")
    loaded_graph = tf.get_default_graph()

    # get necessary tensors by name
    input_tensor_name = model.signature_def[signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY].inputs[signature_constants.CLASSIFY_INPUTS].name
    input_tensor = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name(input_tensor_name)
    output_tensor_name = model.signature_def[signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY].outputs[signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_CLASSES].name
    output_tensor = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name(output_tensor_name)

    result = sess.run(output_tensor, {input_tensor: "Some String"})
    print (result)
```

## Update:

Defining the functions and placeholders when loading the savedModel seems to work. However, I don't know why they are not being added to the graph prior to using the builder to save the model

Comment: It would help to see the code you used to create the `SavedModelBuilder` and add your metagraph data.

Comment: `'pyfunc_0'` does not exist where you think it does. Track it and find out why it does not exist.

Comment: @MatthewScarpino I have added more details on how I am saving the model.

Comment: @skbrhmn, it looks like `tf.saved_model.loader.load` can't access the `input_text` tensor that you provided in your `SavedModel` signature. Without more code, I can't figure out anything further.

Comment: @MatthewScarpino I think I figured out the problem. The function `preprocess` that I defined prior to loading the checkpoint and saving the Model is getting lost when I am loading the model and using it through SavedModel CLI or a a different load.py script. If I define the `preprocess` function and the new placeholders in my load.py script, everything seems to work. How do I add the new placeholders and functions to the graph when I save the model for serving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preprocess function that was being used was not really part of the graph, so py_func() wouldn't know which function to use when loading the savedModel. There is currently no easy way to do preprocessing within Tensorflow Serve flow. It has to be done on the client side before using the model, or a custom op may have to be created so that it can be a part of the model. The other alternative may be to create a custom servable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your model has a custom layer. You can follow the model code and find that. So, you can define that function before graph loading. Also, the function definition order is important.

Comment: Once the model was trained and was saved as a checkpoint. I created the graph again but added new placeholders one of which gets its value from using py_func(). Then I load the checkpoint and then save the model using savedModel builder. So I am defining the function before loading the checkpoint. What am I doing wrong?